# JSF Form Authentication + OAuth

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, oauth, form-authentication

I would like to allow user to login using either Form or OAuth authentication.

For Form authentication, I use a JDBC Realm (running on glassfish server) and do
`HttpServletRequest.login(username, password)` in controller.

This allows access to pages constrained in `web.xml` with `security-constraint`.

To allow facebook login I use socialauth library. With that, I can see the facebook user's data in controller, but the user can't access the secured pages as I don't know how to do `login(username, password)` because I apparently don't have the user's password.

What should I do? Do I have to implement a custom Realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What should I do? Do I have to implement a custom Realm?*

Nope. Just auto-register it as a new user.

Remember to mark in DB whether it's a social account or not, and also remember to check beforehand if the login name (the email address) is associated with a social account or not.

Comment: Ok, but after registration, how do I log him in with FB? I can't do HttpServletRequest.login(...) since I don't have a password. And if I don't do the login, the user can't access restricted pages.

Comment: Just keep the password null or use a default or generate one based on login name and a salt. With a successful social auth you've namely already the confirmation that it's a valid user. Perhaps you'll by now finally understand the last paragraph of the answer better.

Comment: Oh I do know! I wanted to have one user for both form login and oauth login, didn't think of having separate connected users. Thanks for that suggestion.